# Проблема с передачей данных между activity

Tags: android, listview

Я хочу получать данные из второго activity и выводить их в listView в первом, но почему-то на экране ничего не появляется.

Сам код:

Первое activity, в нем я создаю второе activity и вывожу на экран listView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public List<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.array_adapter, list);

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String item = data.getStringExtra("main");

        list.add(item);
    }

    public void floatinButton1OnClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddElement.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Второе activity, в нем я считываю данные из editText и передаю их в первое activity

```
public class AddElement extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_element);
    }

    public void floatingButton1OnClick_AddElement(View view) {

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.editText1_add_element);
        String main_item = textView.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("main", main_item);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: В конец  onActivityResult добавьте adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно "подсказать" адаптеру, что данные обновились. Для этого нужно сделать его доступным за пределами метода `onCreate()` (объявить полем) и вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged()` после добавления элемента:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public List<String> list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.array_adapter, list);

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String item = data.getStringExtra("main");

        list.add(item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void floatinButton1OnClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddElement.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можешь пояснить почему list public, a ArrayAdapter private?

Comment: @Харрис по-хорошему, всё должно быть `private`.